# Whats the correct Go way to do handle errors

Tags: go

This seems a bit stupid, surely theres a better way?

```
err = SendMessageAndWait(db, "this is a test")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error sending message", err)
    return
}
err = DoSomething(db, "this is a test")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error sending message", err)
    return
}
err = CheckSomething(db, "this is another test")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error sending message", err)
    return
}
err = SendMessageAndWait(db, "this is a third test")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error sending message", err)
    return
}
... x10 ...
```

**Update:** For the record, 5 years on from when I wrote this, I am now persuaded that this is a completely sufficient, and perhaps even better, way to handle errors clearly. Not saying its pretty though.

Comment: There is an interesting discussion about GO error handling (and a proposal to change it) in the following link: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/32437

Comment: Yep, thanks for sharing this for others to see here. Reading that proposal is what turned my opinion around and caused me to update the post. I don't think there are better alternatives (that I have seen).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly that's the way it is in Go, however in a way you can make it cleaner:

```
func isError(err error, pre string) error {
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("%v: %v", pre, err)
    }
    return err
}

func isErrorBool(err error, pre string) (b bool) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("%v: %v", pre, err)
        b = true
    }
    return
}

func checkSomething() error {
    return nil
}

func main() {
    if err := isError(checkSomething(), "something failed"); err != nil {
        return /* err */
    }

    //if you don't want to return the error, just check it and die.
    if isErrorBool(checkSomething(), "something else failed") { 
        return
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would not just print an error and return nothing: the idea is to act on the error *and* return it (if no decisive action was taken, like a simple log).
Simply calling `return` is like ignoring the error completely as far as the rest of the application is concerned.

See "[Best Practices for Errors in Go](http://justinas.org/best-practices-for-errors-in-go/)", which includes advices as:

#### Predefine errors

> Given a small set of errors, the best way to handle this is to predefine each error publicly at the package level.

#### Provide information

custom error type is the best solution to this problem. Go's implicit interfaces make creating one easy

#### Provide stack traces

> package [errgo](https://github.com/juju/errgo) provides the functionality of wrapping an error into another one that records where the error happened.

(You have the same features in [`dropbox/godropbox/errors/errors.go`](https://github.com/dropbox/godropbox/blob/master/errors/errors.go))

Comment: Thanks, this is all important information. The code was meant to be an example to demonstrate the problem, not perfectly idiomatic code. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2):

In Go, always check for errors. For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func doStuff() error {
    err := SendMessageAndWait(db, "this is a test")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    err = DoSomething(db, "this is a test")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    err = CheckSomething(db, "this is another test")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    err = SendMessageAndWait(db, "this is a third test")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    err := doStuff()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error sending message", err)
    }
}
```

Comment: It still seems clunky, the err if statement will have to be there 20-30 times on some functions, but this is an improvement (:

Comment: If your functions have 20-30 calls to other functions, consider breaking things up.

Answer (score 2):

Given your lack of context, I can only assume you're returning from `func main()`.

http://play.golang.org/p/pgcwMb647A

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "log"
  "errors"
)

func foo(x int) error {
  if x == 3 {
    return errors.New("x == 3")
  }
  fmt.Println(x)
  return nil
}

func main() {
  check := func(err error) {
    if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
    }
  }

  check(foo(1))
  check(foo(2))
  check(foo(3))
  check(foo(4))
}
```

Generally, explicit handling is the way to go, but there's a variety of things you can do depending on the context.

Answer (score 2):

At the risk of turning this into code golf, Go supports single line if statements with assignments in them:

```
if err := SendMessageAndWait(db, "this is a test"); err != nil {
    return err
}
```

The downside is that all return values assigned are scoped to the corresponding `if`/`else if`/`else` block, so if you actually need a different returned value outside that block, you have to go with something closer to PeterSO's answer.